# Cypress testing: setting opacity for an element to 0 in a React app in order to hide it

Tags: javascript, css, cypress

I'm struggling to understand how to set the opacity of an element to 0, or in any event to hide it, so that I can access elements it is hiding and preventing Cypress from interacting with.

I've tried the native .blur() that's bundled with Cypress to no effect.

The element in question is a dropdown box.  Manually, the only way to close it is to click on the main page body. I want to click on the next dropdown so that it opens and can make selections - but it is 'hidden'.

My test snippet:

```
it('Select Houses', function () {
cy.selectMainMenu();
clickByLabelText(page, 'Sector')
cy.get(.......
})

it('Select Pricing', function () {
cy.selectMainMenu();
clickByLabelText(page, 'Pricing')
cy.get(........
})
```

The dropdown markdown is as follows:

```
<div class="MuiPaper-root MuiMenu-paper MuiPaper- 
elevation8 MuiPopover-paper MuiPaper-rounded" 
role="document" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 1; 
transform: none; min-width: 200px....>
```

I'm unclear how I can directly manipulate the DOM to set the opacity to '0' or to comment it out such that:

```
style="/*opacity: 1; */
```

I don't believe the app is using JQuery.

My error is:

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element:

<a class="App_navItem__3Eb6P App_navItemForceFocus__2xkR3" href="/pricing" aria- 
current="page">Pricing</a>

is being covered by another element:
```

I've tried using {force: true} to click on another dropdown but no joy.  Also, I can't see that the other dropdowns meet the criteria for 'Hidden' as outlined here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Visibility

Comment: Hmm I think if you wan't to decide which element is "on top" and will be clicked, you should set `z-index` instead of opacity, or?

Comment: @DurkoMatko quite probably - but no z--index is exposed in the code when the element is inspected so I'm not clear how I do that